# How to edit Sublime Text 3 Soda Theme

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, soda

I installed the Soda Theme on Sublime Text 3 on OSX and I was wondering where are the actual files and folder to the theme that way I could look at the theme file and make my own edits to it, along with I would like to adjust a few of the images used in the theme.

On the Git documents it says if you are to manually install Soda on Sublime you place the soda folder in the package directory, although when I install Soda via Control Package I don't see the Soda theme in package directory.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Unless explicitly designated to not use it, most packages for Sublime Text 3 use the `.sublime-package` format (essentially a zip file). These packages are stored one directory up from the `Packages` folder, in `Installed Packages`. If you want to work with them, I **highly** recommend getting the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin by @skuroda. Install it via [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).

Once installed, open the command palette with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and type `prv` to get the PackageResourceViewer options. Choose `Extract Package`, navigate down to `Theme - Soda`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you're all set - the directory `Packages/Theme - Soda` should now exist with all the files from the Github repo in it. The `.sublime-theme` files will probably be the ones you're most interested in for now.

Have fun!

Comment: How do you then switch to using the the installed theme? Even after restarting Sublime, I don't see it in any of my Preferences menus.

Comment: @WilsonF - Most theme's documentation includes instructions on how to activate it. For Soda, there are two sets of options - Dark and Light, and Sublime 2 and 3. So, for dark on ST3, the theme name is `Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme`. The same for ST2 would be `Soda Dark.sublime-theme`. In your user preferences, set `"theme": "themename.sublime-theme"` - for example, `"theme": "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme"`. Save your user prefs, restart Sublime, and the new theme will be activated.

Comment: Thanks! When I was looking at the repository, somehow I completely missed the existence of the README file. Duh.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to the accepted solution, but with little more steps if it is not working out of the box. This might help someone if they are stuck with an issue which I have described in one of the below steps.

1. install PackageResourceViewer using Package Control
2. Go to Preferences->Package Settings->PackageResourceViewer->Setting-User. copy paste the following 3 lines,save and close it.

   ```
   {
   "single_command": false
   }
   ```
3. press Ctrl+shift+p to open Package Control and select PackageResourceViewer: Edit Package Resource from the list. Find the package you want to edit and click on it. In my case, I want to edit a theme which is installed via ColorSublime Package, So I selected that theme.
4. Now you will see that the selected package file opened in the sublime editor itself. Edit it as you want and save it and close it. The changes should reflect in sublime editor. In my case, since I changed the theme I need reload it. So I continued with the following steps too.
5. go to view menu select 'Show Console' and run following command to reset the theme.

   ```
   view.settings().erase("color_scheme")
   ```
6. open Preferences->Settings and delete the "color_scheme" attribute and its value from the settings file and close it. Again select the color theme from Preferences->Color scheme. Now you should able to see the changes reflected which you made in the theme package.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows.

1. Extract **Soda theme** from the [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default` folder
2. In Sublime Text **3**, Select **Sublime Text / Preferences / Browse Packages ...**
3. Create a folder adjacent to the **Users** folder called **THEMES**.
4. Drop all themes you want from Sublime Text 2 (including Soda theme or any other themes) from the folder `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default` into your `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/THEMES` folder from Sublime Text 3.
5. Edit the XML in the theme you want to use.
6. Back in Sublime Text 3, select **Sublime Text / Color Schemes / THEMES / YourTheme.tmTheme** to use it.