# How do I extract themes inside of Sublime text's cache, or where are sublime text color schemes located that have been cached?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm on a mac.

also, important to note, a file with a path segment of "Packages/Solarized Color Scheme/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme" does not exist **anywhere** on the filesystem. Sublime text has some sort of caching mechanism here that I don't understand. there is a cache folder, containing binary files that are named similarly (specifically appended with .cache) but sublime text does not recognize them as something it can use.

in my preferences i have this line:

```
"color_scheme": "Packages/Solarized Color Scheme/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme"
```

But, the path `Packages/Solarized Color Scheme/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme` does not exist anywhere on my computer. I'd like to copy my theme to a new computer but I can't seem to find it. I ran `sudo find / | grep tmTheme` which did not find it. Sublime text must have a cache of some sort, with a virtual theme directory? seems weird.

To state again, I ran this command:

```
sudo find / | grep tmTheme
```

And it did not turn up. So, the file path `Packages/Solarized Color Scheme/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme` does not exist anywhere on my system, not in `~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Solarized Color Scheme/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme` or anywhere else.

Comment: Why are you running a `sudo` command on a Windows computer?

Comment: @MattDMo when did i say i was using windows? ???

Comment: `%APPDATA%` is a Windows variable. If not Windows, then what OS *are* you using?

Comment: I just copied that from @maccartm answer.. the goal was to reduce confusion which seems to have failed. the point I'm trying to make is that the is not located anywhere on my filesystem.

Comment: So what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sublime Text 3 stores its default packages and many plugins (installed via Package Control) as zipped `.sublime-package` files. On OS X, Package Control packages are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages`. To access the contents of these packages, the use of the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin is highly recommended. Once installed, open the Command Palette, type ***`prv`***, then select `PackageResourceViewer: Extract Package`. Scroll through the options and select your package of interest, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. All the files in the package will be extracted into `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/<Package Name>`. You can then browse through the source, make changes, or whatever.

However, please be aware that any package upgrades will not take effect, as the `Packages` directory takes precedence over `Installed Packages`.

Comment: Thanks! but I don't see my file in the list. The file (i think) is located at "Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Cache/Solarized Color Scheme/Solarized (dark).tmTheme.cache" which doesn't show up in the list.. should I copy it somewhere else?

Comment: @quinn you don't want the cache file. Did you successfully install PackageResourceViewer and extract the `Solarized Color Scheme` package? You can browse the `Packages` folder in Finder by selecting **`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**.

Comment: Thanks, that's where I was getting tripped up.

Comment: Thanks SO much for this. I was tearing my hair out trying to find these files.

Answer (score 1):

The file could be harder to find due to it being Sublime Text 3. I don't personally use ST3 but from what I understand, ST3 packages run from `*.sublime-package` files. Try using the following program to view the contents of these zipped folders.

https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer

Reference:

https://sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13674

Another edit:

[How to edit Sublime Text 3 Soda Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768637/how-to-edit-sublime-text-3-soda-theme)

Should work for you as well, once again recommending *PackageResourceViewer*

Comment: hey, tried to clarify in my question.. the `sudo find` would have picked up if it were in any of the directories your describing here, so this is a no go. I updated the question again to try to clarify this.

Comment: thanks for the update, but i'm still stuck on the PackageResourceViewer step. I think there is an intermediate step to make the tmTheme.cache file available to PackageResourceViewer.

Answer (score 0):

try to hit on the menu Preferences->Color Scheme on your new PC!

It should work since looks like one of the default themes!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Mine is actually slightly different than the default solarized theme unfortunately, so that won't work.

Comment: Ok! Sorry I didn't understand that it was different!