# Sublime 3 Text Theme Is Blacked Out

Tags: sublimetext3

I followed the instructions from the answers in this question

[Why do Sublime Text 3 Themes not affect the sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931448/why-do-sublime-text-3-themes-not-affect-the-sidebar)

But my sidebar gets blacked out completely. You can't see any folders or text. I've even restarted Sublime and still no luck.

This is my code in my Preferences.sublime-settings - User file

```
{
  "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
  "theme": "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme"
}
```

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: any screenshot of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replicated this on my own machine.

First delete `"theme": "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme"` from your user preferences first.  Then follow the instructions by @MattDMo [How to edit Sublime Text 3 Soda Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768637/how-to-edit-sublime-text-3-soda-theme).  Essentially you'll want to pull the theme onto your machine before invoking the theme in your preferences through the addition of `"theme": "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme"` back to your preferences.  I didn't need to restart my editor for this.  I'm using Sublime3 on my Windows 10 machine.